# Spring-Integration-Splunk dependency issue

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle, splunk

I am trying to include `splunk` logging with my `spring-mvc` project. 
When I add the following dependency to my gradle build:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-splunk', version: '1.1.0.RELEASE'
```

I get following error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtimeCopy'.
   > Could not find com.splunk:splunk:1.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/praveen/.m2/repository/com/splunk/splunk/1.3.0/splunk-1.3.0.pom
         file:/Users/praveen/.m2/repository/com/splunk/splunk/1.3.0/splunk-1.3.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/splunk/splunk/1.3.0/splunk-1.3.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/splunk/splunk/1.3.0/splunk-1.3.0.jar
     Required by:
         :searchMart:unspecified > org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-splunk:1.1.0.RELEASE
```

I tried to look installing the `splunk` version that it could not find but that also is throwing error. Any clues on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

`spring-integration-splunk` is hosted on maven central. However to download `splunk` itself you need to define additional repo:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://splunk.artifactoryonline.com/splunk/ext-releases-local'
    }   
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-splunk:1.1.0.RELEASE'
}

task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: thank you that resolved the issue .
But I eclipse still cant seem to find SplunkLogEvent class. Would you by anychance know as to why ?

Comment: @Praveen, sorry not using eclipse at all. Maybe try to clear cache and restart the project.

Comment: @Praveen, if my answer solved the problem with dependency, please accept the answer.